# search query dynamically inserted into metadescription?

Tags: html

I'm long since retired from IT so please forgive me if this question appears like I'm not an expert - because I'm not!

I have noticed several times when I have done Google searches that some or all of my search terms mysteriously appear in the metadescription of some of the search results that are displayed to me. (sorry, I don't have any current examples.) Is this a known process? if so, what is the term for it please.

tia
Steve